# Weblogic 12c automatically going down

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

The weblogic 12c admin server is shutting down automatically after getting started so the gui web page start giving error that the page cannot be displayed but the managed servers are running the whole time even when the admin server goes down.......plz suggest any fix for this

Comment: SO is for programming questions.  Look in the log files.

Comment: you have to be more specific. Normally, managed servers cannot be running when the controlling admin server goes down. What do you see in the admin server log?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem with your JVM space, check if you have enougth memory to start.